# MySQL SELECT Statement query join 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when I write query select statement I have a lot of row duplicated. My table like this:

**tbl_injection**
[image]

**tbl_patient**
[image]

My Expect result is wanted to return a row because my table tbl_patient has only 1 row. And I just want to get the injection_status from tbl_injection.

Comment: But you want the injection_status of which record? Your relationship for the tables tbl_patient --> tbl_injection is one to many - meaning one patient can have multiple injections - so if you join, which records injection status do you want?

Comment: what query have you tried???

Comment: <b>This is my query that I have tried:</b>
[Code Here][1]


  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8

Comment: Since your relationship is based on the patient_id, the query doesn't know WHICH injection_status you want - there are 16 of them. You need to filter that list down, by using the date field, or something else, if you want to retrieve one row.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like patient_id is not unique enough. Try to put more filter such as injection_date maybe?
Or you can return the result of "latest" injection_status instead.

Answer (score -1):

As you see, **patient_id** value 1 of **tbl_patient** is recorded 16 times in **tbl_injection** table, So you can not one low by using **patient_id** column only.

If you don't want to change those table records, you have to make a query additional columns, such as **injection_data** which has unique value.